# Handle multiple Cameras using Flask and OpenCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, flask, bootstrap-4

While Testing the live video streaming (laptop and USB webcam) through flask, I am not able to display the video streaming on the main page as well as while accessing the decorator. My main aim is to access multiple cameras through using flask mentioned below is the code I am working on

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
import cv2

app = Flask(__name__)

def find_camera(id):
    cameras = ['0','1']
    print(cameras[id])
    return cameras[int(id)]
#  for cctv camera use rtsp://username:password@ip_address:554/user=username_password='password'_channel=channel_number_stream=0.sdp' instead of camera
#  for webcam use zero(0)


def gen_frames(camera_id):

    cam = find_camera(camera_id)
    cap= cv2.VideoCapture(cam)

    while True:
        # for cap in caps:
        # # Capture frame-by-frame
        success, frame = cap.read()  # read the camera frame
        if not success:
            break
        else:
            ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            frame = buffer.tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')  # concat frame one by one and show result


@app.route('/video_feed/<string:id>/', methods=["GET"])
def video_feed(id):

    """Video streaming route. Put this in the src attribute of an img tag."""
    return Response(gen_frames(id),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


@app.route('/', methods=["GET"])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

HTML page

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Multiple Live Streaming</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-7">
            <h3 class="mt-5">Multiple Live Streaming</h3>
            <img src="{{ url_for('video_feed', id='0') }}" width="100%">
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Being a beginner to this I need to know whether we need to use multithreading for handling multiple cameras at a time?

Any suggestions on this will be a great help.

Comment: To answer your other question, yes it is recommended to use multithreading if you would like lag free video streams. You can try and see if you can access the cameras via VLC player using the ip addresses instead of those IDs (i haven't worked with bootstrap for multiple cameras). If i remember correctly as well, opencv uses ffmpeg as its backend for videostreaming, you may want to take a look at Gstreamer as it is more powerful iirc. Ffmpeg is a bit laggy and may drop frames.

Comment: I am trying to run this code everything working perfectly fine but I am not to open both the cameras can you please tell me where is the problem in the script?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, it would be much better to use `ip addresses` and loop through them. It would make for much better clarity ion your code. Your flask code would in-turn look like this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
import cv2

app = Flask(__name__)

# list of camera accesses
cameras = [
 "rtsp://username:password@ip_address:554/user=username_password='password'_channel=channel_number_stream=0.sdp",
 "rtsp://username:password@ip_address:554/user=username_password='password'_channel=channel_number_stream=0.sdp", 
...
  ]


def find_camera(list_id):
    return cameras[int(list_id)]


def gen_frames(camera_id):
    cam = find_camera(camera_id)  # return the camera access link with credentials. Assume 0?
    # cam = cameras[int(id)]
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(cam)  # capture the video from the live feed

    while True:

        # # Capture frame-by-frame. Return boolean(True=frame read correctly. )
        success, frame = cap.read()  # read the camera frame
        if not success:
            break
        else:
            ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            frame = buffer.tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')  # concat frame one by one and show result


@app.route('/video_feed/<string:list_id>/', methods=["GET"])
def video_feed(list_id):
    return Response(gen_frames(list_id),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


@app.route('/', methods=["GET"])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', camera_list=len(cameras), camera=cameras)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Notice how I get the length of my list of `camera addresses` and the whole list in the `index` function. I'm using this because I want to assume the code will just keep adding/removing feeds to the template file if any camera credential is provided or removed.

Your template file would then look something like this:

```
 {% for camera_number in range(0, camera_list) %}
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <img src="{{ url_for('video_feed', list_id=camera_number) }}" width="100%"><br/>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

Here, you would get the length of the list of cameras its list as well from where you can pass to the URL. This should work. Do reach out if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working with multiple camera aswell, here with my current work at viewing more than 5 cameras.
as your trouble you want to view 2 camera isn't it? my_list array is used in jinja2 in html codes it represent how many exactly your camera is.
change your code to:

app.py

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
return render_template('index.html', my_list=[0,1])
```

and index.html, just loop based on my_list array to view how many frame you want to show in index.html

```
{% for n in my_list %}
<div class="col-lg-7">
        <h3 class="mt-5">Multiple Live Streaming</h3>
        <img src="{{ url_for('video_feed', id=n) }}" width="100%">
</div>
{% endfor %}
```